# dynamic memory allocation with arrays in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to insert an int into an array that is in a class object, and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. The current state of my code never inserts the int into the array.

Basically what I am trying to do is when i call insert(int) it will check to to see if there is any room left in the array, and if there is it will add it, otherwise it would reallocate with 8 more spaces in the array.

here is some relevant class info

```
private:

    unsigned Cap;    // Current capacity of the set
    unsigned Num;    // Current count of items in the set
    int * Pool;      // Pointer to array holding the items

  public:

    // Return information about the set
    //
    bool is_empty() const { return Num == 0; }
    unsigned size() const { return Num; }
    unsigned capacity() const { return Cap; }

    // Initialize the set to empty
    //
    Set()
    {
      Cap = Num = 0;
      Pool = NULL;
    }
```

here is the code i am working on

```
bool Set::insert(int X)
{
        bool Flag = false;
        if (Num == Cap)
        {
                //reallocate
                const unsigned Inc = 8;

                int * Temp = new int[Cap+Inc];

                for (unsigned J=0;J<Num;J++)
                {
                        Temp[J] = Pool[J];
                }

                delete [] Pool;
                Pool = Temp;
                Cap = Cap+Inc;
        }

        if(Num < Cap)
        {
                Pool[Num+1] = X;

                Flag = true;
        }
        return Flag;
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the `Flag` --- looks like `insert` can never return  `false`.

Comment: How I wish C++ had a vector "renew" operator that would act like realloc(), but with the additional bonus construct/destruct objects that are added/removed from the end of the hard array being expanded/reduced.

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of simply using `::std::vector`?

Comment: @WhozCraig: Actually, what I would like is a `realloc` that returns an error if it can't expand the size of your allocation in place. Then you could choose whatever means you wanted to move the memory around. And anyway, `::std::vector` in C++11 already does this.

Comment: @Omnifarious The *standard library* does (through std::vector etc). The *language*, however does not, and still does not through C++11. I've always wanted it and never understood why it wasn't proffered up in the standard debates.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Because it's so complex to implement with so many options that it should really be part of the standard library. Personally I think it's complex enough that `new` allocates memory at all. I think there should only be placement `new` and you need to use something like `malloc` to allocate the memory.

Comment: @Omnifarious Oh I'm sure there are reasons it wasn't done, but "'cause its hard" isn't a valid one as far as I'm concerned. And total-props on your comment about realloc(). I *love* that function (it literally is an entire memory manager in a single API) and the attribute you describe is the *one* thing it is truly missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `insert` function never updates `Num`. Try `Pool[Num++] = X;` or something like that.

Comment: thanks, i have been staring at this for too long. i think its time for a break :D

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to increment the number of element but only **after** copying the new element in: the first element should have index 0. Basically, your `insert()` function should look something like this:

```
bool Set::insert(int X)
{
    if (Num == Cap)
    {
        const unsigned Inc(std::max(8, 2 * Cap));
        std::unique_ptr<int[]> Temp(new int[Cap+Inc]);
        std::copy(Pool.get(), Pool.get() + Num, Temp.get());
        Pool.swap(Temp);
        Cap += Inc;
    }
    Pool[Num] = X;
    ++Num;

    return true;
}
```

Of course, this assumes that `Pool` is reasonably declared as `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` (or something with similar functionality which is easy to write if necessary). The reason to use `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` rather than raw pointers is that they automatically clean up resources when they are destroyed. Copying a sequence of `int`s won't throw an exception but if `int` get's replaced by a `std::string` or a template parameters there is potential to throw exceptions.

Comment: If the assignment to `Pool` can throw an exception, wouldn't the line `Pool[Num++] = X;` still violate the basic guarantee?

Comment: @DyP: good point. I'll fix that. Thanks! It wouldn't violate the basic guarantee (the object still can be successfully destroyed), though, but with the small change the code should yield the strong guarantee.

Comment: I thought of the class' invariants: Num could be interpreted as the number of (successfully) assigned elements. Maybe my wording was wrong.

Comment: These are two of the [exception guarantees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_guarantees): The basic exception guarantee means that you don't leak resources and objects can be cleaned up if an exception is thrown from within their methods. The strong exception guarantee means that the class didn't change if an exception is thrown (and, of course, no resources are leaked). In any case, the original code needed improvement...

Comment: ^^ I've read that article before the first comment and thought, the basic would be most adequate to cite here. I thought of the invariant as "the number of successfully assigned elements is the same as `Num`", as you could rely on that relation from outside. As I understand wikipedia's definition (which has btw. the same wording as [this boost article](http://www.boost.org/community/exception_safety.html), you had to undo the capacity change for the strong guarantee.

Comment: This is an interesting thought but I'm not sure I buy that: The program state is constituted by many things and calling, e.g., `delete[] new int[10];` can change the program state in funny ways. In particular, there may be more memory attributed to the program before the call. My interpretation of the strong guarantee is that the salient attributes of the objects didn't change. That would allow a capacity change but not an increase in the size.